# iOS development using Flash CS5 problems

Tags: ios, adobe, flash-cs5

I've followed Adobe's instructions on how to develop iOS app using Flash CS5. Went through all the steps and was able to install my app on my ipad and iphone.  The problem is that it didn't work!

If I upload a simple hello world flash app that works fine.  But when I port my game to it which uses the Pushbutton engine and Box2d etc. all I get is a white screen on iPad and a black screen on the iphone.  It doesn't crash.  It just doesn't do anything. Anyone encounter this?  I don't get any errors or anything.

So I don't know why it doesn't work.  When I run the app on my PC it looks ok and works. This behavior is only when I install it on my device.  I'm using Flash cs5 with the latest updates for ios development.

If anyone knows how to get around this or how I can get more information about what its doing or any errors it is getting that would be very helpful. Thank you!

I am using this type of tag in my Document class.  I wonder if it doesn't like it:

```
[SWF(width="1024" , height="768" , frameRate="30" , "--keep-as3-metadata+=TypeHint,EditorData,Embed" )]
    public class DocumentClass extends Sprite
```

Comment: Have you had a look at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2780918df124b3c90179-8000.html ?

Comment: Thank you. I just followed the instructions for remote debug. I see no errors.  I'm going to put trace statements to see where it stops.

Comment: I don't get any traces.  It never goes in to my document class constructor.

Comment: I am new to Pushbutton engine and it seems like it will work for what we need to do, but I don't want to waste my time with it if it is not going to work on iOS. So just to clarify were you able to use a work around to still use the pushbutton engine or did you just take some pieces of the engine out and use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was that the embedding system in pushbutton engine is not supported on the ios for some reason.  So what I did was use the runtime loading of assets in pushbutton engine and then made sure that those were included in the ipa file for ios to load.  And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the PushButton Engine team, and to be clear... the problem isn't PushButton Engine. There is a bug in the Adobe Flex SDK 4.5 which breaks the ResourceManager inside of PushButton Engine.

> I’ve run into a bug with the released version of the Adobe Flex 4.5 SDK. The 4.5 version of the SDK does not respect keeping [Embed] metadata in your SWF. This is problematic because we use this metadata extensively in PushButton Engine.

More information can be found here:
http://blog.natebeck.net/2011/05/flex-sdk-4-5-doesnt-keep-embed-metadata/

The bug is currently under investigation at Adobe:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-30485

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add Flex compiler argument to retain custom metadata tags:
`--keep-as3-metadata+=TypeHint,EditorData,Embed,ResourceType`